# Rows to columns in azure data explorer (kusto)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a simple query:

```
let startDate = ago(7d);
let endDate = now();
let all_logs = materialize(MyTable | where TIMESTAMP > startDate and TIMESTAMP < endDate | where EventName == "SessionResult");
all_logs
| summarize 
Total_Sessions = count(),
Successful_Sessions = countif(Successful == "True"),
Failed_Sessions = countif(Successful == "False")
| extend Success_Rate = round(100.0*Successful_Sessions/Total_Sessions, 2)
```

Which returns

[image]

How can I change this to:

Label Count Rate

Total_sessions 98 100

Successful_session 96 97.96

Failed_session 2 2.04

preferably without using the pivot plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try using the `narrow()` plugin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/narrowplugin

For example:

```
let T = materialize(
    MyTable 
    | where TIMESTAMP > startDate and TIMESTAMP < endDate
    | where EventName == "SessionResult")
    | summarize 
         Total_Sessions = count(),
         Successful_Sessions = countif(Successful == "True"),
         Failed_Sessions = countif(Successful == "False")
)
;
let total = toscalar(T | project total_sessions)
;
T
| evaluate narrow()
| project Label = Column, Count = Value, Rate = round(100.0 * tolong(Value) / total, 2)
```